# heroku push rejected, complaining using the 'match' method in router, even though i am using 'get'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am using Rails 4.0.2
When I try to push my app to heroku, it rejects it, with the message:

rake aborted!
       You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.

```
   If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
   If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:
   Instead of: match "controller#action"
   Do: get "controller#action"
   /tmp/build_e1d9b463-4a69-445b-b695-62ec1d8ef566/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:191:in `normal
```

ize_conditions!'

```
   /tmp/build_e1d9b463-4a69-445b-b695-62ec1d8ef566/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:67:in `initial
```

ize'
       /tmp/build_e1d9b463-4a69-445b-b695-62ec1d8ef566/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1443:in `new'
       /tmp/build_e1d9b463-4a69-445b-b695-62ec1d8ef566/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1443:in`add_r
oute'
...

My routes.rb looks like this:

Agudasinthecity::Application.routes.draw do

```
root             :to => 'pages#home'
get '/where',    :to => 'pages#where'
get '/when',     :to => 'pages#when'
get '/contact',  :to => 'contact_us/contacts#new'
```

end

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to add via: 'get' at the end of every route (except for the root)